# Spring Email with Thymeleaf sending HTML code

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to send an email with spring boot and template Thymeleaf. Theoretically everything works,email is sended, but in practice the recipient gets the clean HTML code. I don't know what is wrong. The template code is probably correct. Can you tell me what's wrong?

```
@Service
public class MailService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("JavaEmailConfig")
    public JavaMailSender emailSender;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("templateEngine")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;


    public String build(Object object, String temp) {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("object", object);
        return templateEngine.process(temp, context);
    }

    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, Object object, String temp) {
        MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            messageHelper.setTo(to);
            messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
            String content = build(list,object,temp);
            messageHelper.setText(content);
        };
        try {
            emailSender.send(messagePreparator);
        } catch (MailException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

MailConfig:

```
@Configuration
    public class MailConfig {


        private String host="smtp.gmail.com";
        private String port="587"
        private String username;
        private String password;


        @Bean(name = "JavaEmailConfig")
        public JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender() {
            JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
            mailSender.setHost(host);
            mailSender.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));

            mailSender.setUsername(username);
            mailSender.setPassword(password);

            Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");

            return mailSender;
        }
    }
```

Simply code temp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello! I`m sending email :) </p>
</body>
</html>
```